# the partition contains one or more dynamic volumes that are not supported for installation ( Error while installing windows server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-server-2008, boot-partition

I have installed Win 7 on C Drive of my computer . I formatted Drive D in Windows ( Right Click and Format ... )  and now when i try to install Win 2008 R2 on D Drive from Boot i get this error :

```
 Windows cannot be installed to this Hard disk space .
 The partition contain one or more volumes that are not supported for installation .
```

And the drive is disabled , So i can't Format , Delete and so on .

//More info : Before I installed both OS ( 7 & Server 2008) And i have this problem when i formatted D drive ( server 2008 ) on Windows environment .

I appreciate any help for installing again Windows server 2008 R2 .

Comment: Did you convert the disk to a "dynamic disk" at some point?

Comment: I just right clicked and Formated by default settings ,Even now I don't see any option for "dynamic disk" or else !

Comment: Formatting is an operation performed on the partition. The dynamic disk option appears when you right click the "Disk X" entry in the lower half panel of the Disk Management snap-in. The disk itself would then, most likely, also be labelled as "Dynamic" instead of "Basic".

Comment: Screenshot of disk management for that drive would be helpful.

Comment: @Olver: I'm sure there is no such this option for me . I'm suing windows 7 , Could you please tell me more specific ?

Comment: Start `diskpart`.  Paste the output of its `list disk`, `list partition`, and `list volume` commands in your question.